# RxJS concat/merge async request with timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to make RxJS observable which will make async request and timeout at the same time.

`-> promise -> filter -> promise and timeout -> complete`
In synchronous version with async/await code looks like this:

```
(async () => {
  const gameInfo = await function1(); // return undefined or {start, id}

   if (!gameInfo) {
     return;
   }

  const gameStart = gameInfo.start;

  setTimeout(() => {
     function3(gameInfo._id).then(res => {
         console.log('Done');
     });
  }, getDelayTime(gameStart));

 await function2();

 // Completed
})();

const getDelayTime = (time) => {
  const now = new Date();
  const parsedTime = new Date(time);

  console.log('In delay', parsedTime.getTime() - now.getTime());
  return parsedTime.getTime() - now.getTime();
};
```

So the goal is to receive some data asynchronously from `function1()`, then make some operations with first part of it and at the same time started timer, to make second operation when time ends, not matter wether `function3()` end or not.

So, in RxJS I came with something like this:

```
Rx.Observable
  .fromPromise(function1())
  .filter(data => data)
  .concatMap(data => {
    Rx.Observable.fromPromise(function2());
    Rx.operators.delay(data => Rx.operators.timeout(getDelayTime(data.start)));
  })
  .subscribe(
    data => {
       console.log('Data', data); 
       function3(data._id)
    }
    err => console.error('Err', err.message),
    () => console.log('Completed'),
  );
```

But, it's not working as expected for my goal.

If I change my code to something like this:

```
Rx.Observable
  .fromPromise(function1())
  .filter(data => data)
  .delayWhen(data => getDelayTime(data.start)) // or .timeout() or .delay
  .map(data => {Rx.Observable.fromPromise(function2());})
```

It's not working.
So, my question is, **how can I make concurrent timer and async http request in RxJS**?

Comment: You're not returning from `concatMap` and `map`

Comment: @martin I don't want to return something. I want to make async operation and timeout concurrently. If I add `return Rx.Observable.of('ok')` at the end of `concatMap`, async operations keep going in separate process, but `Observable` done it's activity.

Comment: as @martin say, `concatMap` and `map` expect return, see source code here : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/concatMap.ts#L67

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of `function2` and `function3`?

Comment: @bygrace `function3` is independent async process the same is true for `function2`. I want to start processes, but I don't care about returned information

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to delay a call is to do `timer` followed by a `*map` (flatMap, switchMap, ...) operator. It will wait for the duration and then subscribe to whatever you put in the `*map`.

You can subscribe to multiple observables with `combineLatest`, `withLatestFrom`, and similar. But usually one wants to do something with the results.

You could always use the `tap` operator to fire a side-effect if you don't care about the results. Or you could just do it in the `onNext` callback in subscribe.

I think this does what you want but to be honest it is an odd usage. If you could share more about what you are trying to accomplish we could probably give better advice.

```js
function test(id, timeout) {
  console.log('called', id);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('resolved', id);
      resolve();
    }, timeout);
  });
}

Rx.Observable.fromPromise(test(1, 1000))
  .flatMap(() => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    Rx.Observable.fromPromise(test(2, 3000)),
    Rx.Observable.timer(1234).flatMap(() => 
      Rx.Observable.fromPromise(test(3, 100)))
  ))
  .subscribe(() => { console.log('onNext'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.9/Rx.min.js"></script>
```